# How to count number of records in a Postgres Join query

Tags: postgresql, left-join

I have 3 tables A,B,C with foreign keys

B.Aid=A.id

C.Aid=A.id

C.Bid=B.id

Table details below:

Table A

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 3 | name3 |

Table B

| id | Aid | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | xxx |
| 2 | 2 | xxx |
| 3 | 2 | yyy |
| 4 | 2 | xxx |
| 5 | 2 | zzz |
| 6 | 3 | xxx |
| 7 | 3 | zzz |

Table C

| id | Aid | Bid | theme |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | aaa |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | aaa |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | bbb |
| 4 | 2 | 4 | bbb |
| 5 | 2 | 5 | ccc |
| 6 | 2 | null | ddd |
| 7 | 3 | 6 | aaa |
| 8 | 3 | null | bbb |
| 9 | 3 | 7 | ccc |

I am trying to calculate count of records in B and C based on column condition in respective tables.

Expected result:

| A.id | Bcount | Ccount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |

Below is the query written:

```
select 
    A.id,
    sum(
        case
            When B.title = 'xxx' Then 1
            Else 0
        End
    ) as Bcount,
    sum(
        case
            When C.theme = 'aaa' Then 1
            Else 0
        End
    ) as Ccount
From A
LEFT JOIN B on A.id = B.Aid
LEFT JOIN C on A.id = C.Aid
GROUP BY A.id
ORDER BY A.id;
```

Result is coming as:

| A.id | Bcount | Ccount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 30 | 30 |
| 3 | 6 | 6 |

When subqueries are written for each count, it is returning correct results. But it takes more time. How can this be achieved without subquery.

Comment: Try: eliminate the case statements  count your title fields and add conditions on your join and b.title = 'xxx' on join B and C.title = 'aaa'

Answer (score 1):

Are you over thinking this?

Not sure why you couldn't apply your filters to your joins and just count your records and group by your ID.    Note they need to be on the joins and not on the where clause because the filters are applied on the table at the time of the join instead of after the join.  if they were applied in the were clause, the null values generated from the left/outer joins would be negated as the null values generated would be removed.

```
SELECT 
    A.id,
    coalesce(count (b.title),0) as Bcount,  --maybe handling nulls was problem?
    coalesce(count (C.theme),0) as Ccount
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B on A.id = B.Aid  
           and B.title = 'xxx'  
LEFT JOIN C on A.id = C.Aid  
           and C.theme = 'aaa' 
GROUP BY A.id
ORDER BY A.id;
```

after review I thought inner joins would work; but then I looked at record 1  from table A and realized it would fall off; so left joins are needed. and if aaa didn't exist for a xxx it too would fall off..